# Why does this connection code take almost 5 seconds to run?

Tags: node.js, performance, mongodb, npm

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient

var perf = 0
, interval = setInterval(function(){
  perf++;
}, 0);

var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/test';
MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {

  console.log("Finished after", ( perf / 1000 ), "seconds" );
  clearInterval(interval);

});
```

Average output

```
Finished after 4.343 seconds
```

Why is it so ridiculously slow? How can I identify the bottle neck and fix this?

Running on OS X 10.9.5 with the following versions:

```
Node v0.10.33
npm  1.4.28
MongoDB shell version: 2.4.6
```

Comment: This is slightly unrelated, but using `setInterval` in this way is very inefficient. You should instead just do `var start = Date.now();` and then inside the `connect()` callback: `console.log('Finished after', ((Date.now() - start) / 1000 ), 'seconds');`.

Comment: Actually, @mscdex as a test I ran the setInterval version and the Date.now() version on my machine a few dozen times each, and the Date.now() version was consistently slower (by a factor of 4) than the setInterval version.  Average connection speed for setInterval was .007 seconds, but Date.now was .031 seconds.  Not sure why, but there you have it.

Comment: @subZero how does that compare to the startup time of your mongo cli ?

Comment: @Paul The setInterval case is "faster" because there is no requirement that the callback run one time per millisecond, so it could literally come back as anything greater than `0`. Using `Date.now()` or `process.hrtime` is the correct way to measure the time.

Comment: @loganfsmyth, ah, gotcha. I was thrown off by mscdex's use of the word "inefficient", assuming he meant it was consuming extra resources. Not that it was more accurate.  Thanks for clearing it up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the reason, but changing from `"mongodb": "*",` to a specific version in `package.json`, then reinstalling the npm package, resolved the issue, e. g:

```
"mongodb": "^1.4.23",
```